# Background image problem in while making responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I am having little trouble making the background image responsive. It works fine in the desktop.

```
body {
            background:url(../Images/mountain.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;           
        }
```

[image]

This is fine when I don't care for responsiveness, perfectly fit to the window. But,
as I make window smaller the width is maintained perfect but the height of image is shrinking and I get awkward white background.
[image]

Then to solve that I added this,

```
height:100vh;
```

This was nice, my image height was perfectly aligned to window as I made smaller. Though image is also perfectly aligned for desktop and mobile, I am losing the image as I make window smaller. It is being cropped.
[image]

What should I do? Is media queries the only solution? What can I do except media queries with different images?

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. What would you expect? If the image would not be cropped, it would be deformed instead or not cover the body fully. Like you have mentioned, you can "optimize" by using different images for different screen sizes.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Thanks for simple yet clear explanation. Though for a while I thought same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-size` property. Its accepted values are:

- contain : Scales the image as large as possible within its container without cropping or stretching the image
- cover : Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary

Of course it cannot stretch outside of the container (for example if the body element does not take the entire page, you might wanna add `min-height: 100vh;` for that)

Comment: As you can see above, I have already done what you are saying. I appreciate your answer though. That is the best we can go without using media queries.